# Problem Could not switch the monitor configuration - CRTC 64 bug

Tags: nvidia

I have a problem with a double screen configuration on Ubuntu 14.04.

I get this message when I turn on the system:

> Could not switch the monitor configuration could not set the configuration for CRTC 64

And when I'm moving the mouse cursor it leaves a trace.

This started happening when I reinstalled a windows system on ssd and installed Ubuntu on old disc.

My graphics card is nVidia gtx 770.

What should I do?

Comment: Got the same message except "CRTC 442" on a laptop with 16.04 when it woke from sleep.